# Determine the ordinal position of elements in a list

Tags: c#, list, sorting, ordinal

I have a `list` of randomly generated numbers (let's call it `numbers`). I have another `list` of `int` of the same number of elements (I'll call it `positions`). The purpose of positions is to store the ordinal positions of the element. How do I go about this?

This is what I have thought about it:

1. Creating a copy of `numbers` called `copy`
2. Having to link it to `numbers` (sort of)
3. Sorting `copy`
4. Getting the indices of `copy`
5. Storing the associated indices in `positions`

The second step is what I don't know how to go about.

I'm not sure if what I have thought is the best. So I'll actually prefer a better implementation of this.

Comment: If you want an implementation better than the one you currently have, you'd have to *show* your current *implementation* ;-). At any rate, you may have better luck at CodeReview.StackExchange.com (read their FAQ though!).

Comment: And say in what way you're looking for something better. Faster? More maintainable? Easier to use?

Comment: @Jeroen You are right. I don't have access to my code right now. That's why I couldn't post it. As soon as I get it, I'll update the question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Like I said, I've not been able to implement the second step, so obviously anything else that works is better and faster.

Comment: Well it's not clear what your second step even means, to be honest... Oh, and are your numbers distinct?

Comment: Regardless of this actual question, I highly recommend against doing this (posting if you "don't have access to [your] code"). Try to post your questions as complete as possible, and only if you have time to add anything necessary / requested in comments the first 15 mins. The reason I'd say this is two-fold: first, your question gets about 50% of its views in the first few minutes after posting, and second, this way volunteers trying to help don't have to go through incomplete posts.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, they are unique. Really, there are only 5 numbers in the list.

Comment: @Jeroen Noted! Thanks

Comment: If they're distinct (and it's that small), you can just create a copy, sort it, then use `IndexOf`. But DrKoch's solution is nicer, and is really simple to implement.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are absolutely right. Now I have two solutions--yours and DrKoch's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Create Pairs of `int`, for Example `Tuple<int,int>`
2. For each element in `numbers` create a pair with the number and an increasing index
3. Sort your pairs with the first number as a key
4. Now you'll find the `positions` in the second int of your sorted pairs

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, given that it would work pretty simply and would be fairly trivial to implement in LINQ in about 3 lines.

Comment: Quite coincidental?! I was just thinking of trying `tuples`. I hope it works

Comment: Not exactly sure why this answer was downvoted. Maybe SO should start showing people that vote